# Does java optimize multiple logical "not" ot "not equal" in different Methods?

Tags: java, optimization, boolean

Lets look at the example codes as following(modified to have private fields):

```
 public class StupidNot{
 private Object a,b;
 ...
 public boolean notEqual(){
       return a!= b;
 }
}
 public class AnotherStupidNot{
 private StupidNot sn;
 private Whatever obj;

 public boolean anotherNotEqual(){
       return  ! sn.notEqual() && obj.someBoolean()
 }
}
```

...
Etc, the idea is if the JVM or compiler optimizes multiple "not"'s , located in different methods?

Comment: I'd be very surprised if `javac` did; the easiest way to find out would be to decompile the class file. JIT might. However, this is a micro-optimization - write whatever is most sensible for your code.

Comment: Yes i also doubt that JVM would do that, since it does the code of the method almost strictly attached to the class object, (except you you use code injection). A compiler, what does optimization after inlining  :D would do. 
But this shows the general problem, how the code nested to different classes, especially if developed independently, make the code fat.
See the real example - someone writes a class with for example isEmpty,
another uses it in its method with complex boolean statement, and so on, i real software have seen up to 5(!) levels of such ill boolean statements

Comment: More to the point, why would you have the first method in the first place? It's pointless to create a method when you can just use the != operator directly.

Comment: @EJP There are several possible reasons. Using it as method reference in a predicate, or maybe reflection things... (just saying that it *can* be reasonable)

Comment: Javac will certainly not do it, but the JIT will certainly do it. The question is: What is "it"? That is: "Optimize" in which regard? The JIT will, for example, *inline* the `notEqual` method. If there are any doubts, one can look at the JITed code.

Comment: @EJP
emm.. right, but the longer real-world example would be if the fieds to compare are private to the class or complex check happens there, what would be practical to make with inline method.
only if JIT do complete inline of all classes

Answer (score 1):

This is not optimized by javac, but can be easily optimized by JIT compiler if it knows that `StupidNot.notEqual` is never overridden in the loaded subclasses of `StupidNot` (if any). Then `notEqual` will be inlined into `anotherNotEqual` and after inlining this optimization will be performed.

If `StupidNot` class has subclasses and some of them override `notEqual` method, it's still possible that JIT compiler optimizes this case based on Type profile (if it's known, for example, that in most of the cases you are using the `StupidNot` class and not using its subclasses). In this case JIT-compiler would add quick type check to the `anotherNotEqual` method which (if succeed) will use inlined `notEqual` and otherwise will use slow virtual call.

Also don't forget that `anotherNotEqual` could also be inlined into some other method as it's quite simple.